# How to use getLifecycle().addObserver() inside RecyclerView adapter

Tags: android, android-adapter, android-lifecycle, android-youtube-api, android-viewholder

This might be a stupid question for many of you but I can't find a way to use getLifecycle().addObserver() inside RecyclerView adapter.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Maybe it is better to set/get data from adapter there where getLifecycle().addObserver() is living?

Comment: I am trying to use YouTubePlayerView to show youtube videos on recyclerview list which requires to listen app lifecycle.

Comment: I got it, I just need to pass lifecycle from the activity/fragment while setting it on activity/fragment.

Comment: Hope, I have helped :)

Answer (score 4):

I was trying to do the same thing for the YouTubePlayerView and found an elegant way to do this:

First you need to create an interface:

```
public interface AddLifecycleCallbackListener {
    void addLifeCycleCallBack(YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView);
}
```

Then in your activity, implement the above interface and override the method:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AddLifecycleCallbackListener
//...
@Override
public void addLifeCycleCallBack(YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView) {
    getLifecycle().addObserver(youTubePlayerView);
}
```

Finally, inside the adapter, after you initialize the YoutubePlayerView, add this code:

```
((MainActivity) context).addLifeCycleCallBack(youTubePlayerView);
```

You will have to pass the context to the adapter.